# JQuery UI sortable placeholder styling issue

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable, placeholder

I have been trying to figure this out for a friend. They have an HTML5 local music player that allows the user to drag and drop the items in the playlist. However the color of the place holder is not showing up, other elements are such as the height and line-height. Here is the JSFiddle so you can see what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/aYYUU/ Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following. It's because placeholder is an empty row. Just append `td` in it.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aYYUU/2/)</kbd>

HTML

```
<table id="songList">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="check"><input type="checkbox" title="Select All"></th>
        <th id="delete"><button title="Delete Selected"></button></th>
        <th id="play"><button></button></th>
        <th id="artist" style="width: 296px; ">Artist</th>
        <th id="title" style="width: 296px; ">Title</th>
        <th id="album" style="width: 297px; ">Album</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="height: 204px; " class="ui-sortable"><tr class="ui-state-default playing"><td class="check"><input type="checkbox"></td><td class="delete"><button title="Delete From List"></button></td><td class="play"><button></button></td><td class="artist" style="width: 296px; ">Masakazu Sugimori</td><td class="title" style="width: 296px; ">Ace Attorney ~ Prologue</td><td class="album" style="width: 280px; ">Phoenix Wright - Ace Attorney OST</td></tr><tr class="ui-state-default"><td class="check"><input type="checkbox"></td><td class="delete"><button title="Delete From List"></button></td><td class="play"><button></button></td><td class="artist" style="width: 296px; ">Masakazu Sugimori</td><td class="title" style="width: 296px; ">Reminiscence ~ Case DL-6</td><td class="album" style="width: 280px; ">Phoenix Wright - Ace Attorney OST</td></tr><tr class="ui-state-default"><td class="check"><input type="checkbox"></td><td class="delete"><button title="Delete From List"></button></td><td class="play"><button></button></td><td class="artist" style="width: 296px; ">Masakazu Sugimori</td><td class="title" style="width: 296px; ">Rise From The Ashes ~ End</td><td class="album" style="width: 280px; ">Phoenix Wright - Ace Attorney OST</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table input[type=checkbox], table button {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
$('#songList tbody').sortable({
    refreshPositions: true,
    opacity: 0.6,
    scroll: true,
    containment: 'parent',
    placeholder: 'ui-placeholder',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    'start': function (event, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.html("<td colspan='6'></td>")
    }
}).disableSelection();
```